# Symbolic computer algebra system with LaTex editor

Tags: computer-algebra-systems

Is there an equation editor where I can type in an equation, and then work with it interactively, e.g. adding a term to one side will automatically put it on the other, and possibly converge?

For example, if I were completing the square, I could put in the manual terms, then have it compute that step and then add a row for the next step.

Basically, I'd like something like Alpha, but I actually have to do some manual work to document my homework answers, but some of the mechanical grunt work is handled by the system.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of equations that you want to manipulate ?